# dc charts change legend order

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have a stacked chart with legend. I want to change the order of legends without changing chart itself.  i.e. Currently Legend is displayed in following order
 Least
 N/A
 Most
I want to display it as follows
 Most
 N/A
 Least

```
 mostLeastLikelyChart
        .width(leastMostLikelyChartWidth)
        .height(chartHeight)
        .margins(margins1) 
        .dimension(mostLeastLikelyDim)
        .gap(10)  
        .ordinalColors(['#f7a35c','#7cb5ec','#08A4BA'])  
        .group(mostLeastLikelyGrp, "Least", function (d) {      
            return d.value.lst.count;
        })
        .stack(mostLeastLikelyGrp, "N/A", function (d) {
            return d.value.na.count;
        })
        .stack(mostLeastLikelyGrp, "Most", function (d) {
            return d.value.most.count;
        })
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(mostLeastLikelyDim))
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .elasticX(true)
              .legend(dc.legend().x(leastMostLikelyChartWidth*0.80).y(0).itemHeight(13).gap(5).legendText(function(d){return d.name}))
```

Comment: Please share the code of what you have tried so far so people can help you

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for the correction.  Can you please suggest a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yep, getting to it...

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Solution to this problem is very important to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, that is a most annoying default! No wonder you want to change this.

It's completely backwards, since the order of stacks is from bottom to top:

[image: wrong legend order]

Luckily dc.js has a leaky abstraction and so it's really easy to override stuff like this. There is a function `chart.legendables()` which is called internally by the legend in order to retrieve the items to draw in the legend.

You can override it like this:

```
      dc.override(chart, 'legendables', function() {
          var items = chart._legendables();
          return items.reverse();
      });
```

Phew! Much better!
[image: fixed legend order]

I've added this to [the stacked bar example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/stacked-bar.html). Thanks for pointing this out, Farah, maybe we can make an option for this and default it the other way for stacked charts.

#### dc version 4+

In dc@4 and later, the charts use ES6 classes and `dc.override` is gone. You can create a derived class and use `super`, or override the method directly:

```
    const super_legendables = chart.legendables;
    chart.legendables = function() {
        const items = super_legendables.call(this);
        return items.reverse();
    }
```

This is documented [in the dc@4 upgrade guide](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/docs/dc-v4-upgrade-guide.md).

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  It works like a magic.  I think dc charts should have an option to change the legend position.

Comment: This is "order" not "position" - `legend.x()` and `.y()` set the position. But yeah I agree. If this answer helped, please accept it (the green check mark).

Comment: I use dc 4.0.3 with webpack and get following error: 
TypeError: dc__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.override is not a function

Do I need an additonal import for dc.override?

Comment: Hi @Stefan, good point, dc@4 uses ES6 classes and `dc.override` is gone. I've added a section above.